# txt file doesn't read from start after first loop run

Tags: c, loops, file, txt

I've two lists, backedup.txt and current.txt.

backedup.txt contains these lines;

```
Chris_Jamaica.mp3
Chris_Take_Me.mp3
Chris_You_Are_Me.mp3
Chris_Dance_With_Me.mp3
Chris_Yesterday.mp3
```

current.txt contains these lines;

```
Chris_You_Are_Me.mp3
Chris_Dance_With_Me.mp3
Chris_Take_Me.mp3
```

I want to compare item by item in two text files, one item from backedup.txt, compare with all lines in current.txt, then print out if found.

This is the code i have

```
/* compare backedup list with the current list */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *current_list=fopen("/current.txt","r");
    FILE *backedup_list=fopen("/backedup.txt","r");

    char current_list_song[40],backedup_list_song[40];
    
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {

        fscanf(backedup_list,"%s",backedup_list_song);

        for(int j=1; j<=3; j++) {
            fscanf(current_list,"%s",current_list_song);
            if(strcmp(backedup_list_song,current_list_song) != 0) {
                printf("%-30s - %s\n",backedup_list_song, current_list_song);
            }
            else{
                printf("%-30s - Found!\n",backedup_list_song);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(current_list);
    fclose(backedup_list);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the result of running that code

[image: results]

Checking the first line in backedup.txt with the lines in current.txt works, but from the second line in backedup.txt onwards, the current.txt doesn't start checking from the beginning, it just gets stuck on the last line or continues if there are more lines.

I want to be able to check the whole `current.txt`, with every line from `backedup.txt`, always beginning at the start of `current.txt`

Comment: you need to use `fseek()` to go back to the beginning of a file, it doesn't happen automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this before the second for loop:

```
fseek(current_list, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

so you can start over from the beginning.